# Constructing and printing a maze

Tags: python, algorithm, maze

I have implemented a maze with python

- a function addCoordinate where x and y denote the x and y coord of grid and block type: zero means open and 1 means wall.
- a printMaze function which prints the maze with * for wall and empty space for open spaces.
  My

  Implementation seems to be working fine but could there be a better way of doing this:

```
class Maze:
    board, max_x, max_y, list = [],2,2,[]

    def __init__(self):
        """
        Constructor - You may modify this, but please do not add any extra parameters
        """

    def addCoordinate(self, x, y, blockType):
        """
        Add information about a coordinate on the maze grid
        x is the x coordinate
        y is the y coordinate
        blockType should be 0 (for an open space) of 1 (for a wall)
        """
        if x > self.max_x:
            self.max_x = x
        if y > self.max_y:
            self.max_y = y
        if self.max_y >= len(self.board) or self.max_x >= len(self.board[0]):
            newboard = [[1 for a in range(self.max_x + 1)] for b in range(self.max_y + 1)]
            for i in range(len(self.board)):
                for j in range(len(self.board[i])):
                    newboard[i][j] = self.board[i][j]
            self.board = newboard
        self.board[y][x] = blockType
    def printMaze(self):
        """
        Print out an ascii representation of the maze.
        A * indicates a wall and a empty space indicates an open space in the maze
        """

        for i in range(self.max_x + 1):
            for j in range(self.max_y + 1):
                if self.board[i][j] == 0:
                    print " ",
                else:
                    print "*",
            print ""


def mazeTest():
    """
    This sets the open space coordinates for the example
    maze in the assignment.
    The remainder of coordinates within the max bounds of these specified coordinates
    are assumed to be walls
    """
    myMaze = Maze()
    myMaze.addCoordinate(1, 0, 0)
    myMaze.addCoordinate(1, 1, 0)
    myMaze.addCoordinate(7, 1, 0)
    myMaze.addCoordinate(1, 2, 0)
    myMaze.addCoordinate(2, 2, 0)
    myMaze.addCoordinate(3, 2, 0)
    myMaze.addCoordinate(4, 2, 0)
    myMaze.addCoordinate(6, 2, 0)
    myMaze.addCoordinate(7, 2, 0)
    myMaze.addCoordinate(4, 3, 0)
    myMaze.addCoordinate(7, 3, 0)
    myMaze.addCoordinate(4, 4, 0)
    myMaze.addCoordinate(7, 4, 0)
    myMaze.addCoordinate(3, 5, 0)
    myMaze.addCoordinate(4, 5, 0)
    myMaze.addCoordinate(7, 5, 0)
    myMaze.addCoordinate(1, 6, 0)
    myMaze.addCoordinate(2, 6, 0)
    myMaze.addCoordinate(3, 6, 0)
    myMaze.addCoordinate(4, 6, 0)
    myMaze.addCoordinate(6, 6, 0)
    myMaze.addCoordinate(7, 6, 0)
    myMaze.addCoordinate(5, 7, 0)

    myMaze.printMaze()

mazeTest()
```

Is there any data structures i should be using other than a list. i am looking to implement a maze solving algorithm to this maze

Comment: https://github.com/py928/generate-mazes

Comment: Seems kind of silly to be allocating and initializing a new board structure every time your `x` or `y` coordinate exceeds the bounds. Perhaps you could cache all the calls to `addCoordinate`, compute the bounds, and then initialize the board only once. Or you could force the caller to set the bounds when it calls the `Maze` constructor, and have `addCoordinate` reject any calls that try to extend the bounds.